# Compile all jsp on deploy

Tags: java, jsp, webserver, weblogic

I want all my .jsp files to be compiled at deploy instead on first access. Anyone knows how to do it in a webserver agnostic way (through web.xml maybe?). If there is not a way to do this through a project configuration I would like to know how to do it on Weblogic.

Comment: Do you need to precompile jsps at build time or at deployment time?

Comment: @richardtz any one of those is fine.

Comment: For weblogic, you have both approaches here (http://m-button.blogspot.com.es/2008/09/using-jsp-precompilation-in-weblogic.html). I prefer doing it at build time, as it will not impact  application deploy time.

Comment: @richardtz - you should add that comment as an answer - you've given exactly what's needed there.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the server to precompile JSPs on deployment. See section Precompiling JSPs in the [WebLogic JSP Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jsp/reference.html). From there:

> You can configure WebLogic Server to precompile your JSPs when a Web
>   Application is deployed or re-deployed or when WebLogic Server starts
>   up by setting the precompile parameter to true in the 
>   element of the weblogic.xml deployment descriptor. To avoid
>   recompiling your JSPs each time the server restarts and when you
>   target additional servers, precompile them using weblogic.jspc and
>   place them in the WEB-INF/classes folder and archive them in a .war
>   file. Keeping your source files in a separate directory from the
>   archived .war file will eliminate the possibility of errors caused by
>   a JSP having a dependency on one of the class files.
>
> For more information on the web.xml deployment descriptor, see
>   [Assembling and Configuring Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

For weblogic, you have both approaches here (http://m-button.blogspot.com.es/2008/09/using-jsp-precompilation-in-weblogic.html).
I prefer doing it at build time, as it will not impact application deploy time.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get this done is to add the `jsp_precompile` as a request parameter to the desired jsp as in

```
http://localhost/myApp/desired_page.jsp?jsp_precompile=true
```

I personally am not an advocate of sending such a systemic config parameter so obviously in a request, so you should do it within the page (or group of pages) as described in this [tutorial](http://javapapers.com/jsp/how-to-pre-compile-jsp/)