# Weblogic compilation pages

Tags: weblogic

we have a website that uses weblogic 10.3 to serve the pages. The pages are updated from a Content Manager that publish the changes on the pages.

We configured Weblogic to precompile the pages when we start the server using the parameter:

```
<precompile>true</precompile>
```

But If I publish a new page when the weblogic server is running the page is not compiled until a user visits it. Then, the first user that visits the page have to wait 50 seconds to see it.
The next users see the page in 2 seconds because is compiled.

We want to force that weblogic compile the page in the moment that the page is published and it not wait to a user visits these page.

How can we configure weblogic for detecting the changes and new pages published from content manager? How can we configure weblogic to compile these pages inmediatly?

Thank you.

Kind regards,

Gustavo.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before: [Compile all jsp on deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069067/compile-all-jsp-on-deploy)

I would recommend precompiling before deployment if at all possible but you can check out all of the answers there to see what will work for you.

Comment: I don´t want to compile on deploy. I wan't to change a page when the server is running and then compile it before a user access to these page.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without re-deploying the app or cycling the server. Precompiling is the only way around it. http://jojovedder.blogspot.com/2009/05/slow-weblogic-response-jsp-and-servlet.html